# Fade borders of image without box-shadow

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to fade the borders of an image to smoothly blend to the background image.

Like this: [image: Img with faded borders to alpha]

All suggestions in internet are about using box-shadow inset and to set the same solid color to the parent element, but it wouldn't work for my case. Trick with box-shadow with 0.5 alpha or so it's also unuseful.

What could I do? Prefer CSS but maybe canvas and javascript could be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider duplicating the image using pseudo element where I apply blur filter:

```css
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:var(--i);
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:30%;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:var(--i);
  background-position:right;
  filter:blur(20px);
}
.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:30%;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:var(--i);
  filter:blur(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--i:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/)">
</div>
```

Comment: Well, thanks for bring clip-path to my radar, but this snippet keeps the hard borders in the inside image, which I try to avoid.

Comment: @menigonzalez_ you mean what the hard borders in the inside ?

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/iwq3vw) This is the render of the snippet. As you see, the border is not soft, unlike my example.

Comment: @menigonzalez_ ok added another way ;) without clip-path

Comment: That's cool, man. A simple solution after all but nobody had the answer here in the website record. Thanks.